# How do I reference a PHP array from a separate PHP file without using the include function

Tags: php

(Jump straight to the comments in the code section of **sentence_editor.php**)

I am designing the back-end of a programme which allows the administrator to make adjustments to sentences which are stored in a database.

1. Execution starts off from **index.php**.
2. **index.php** includes the file **fetchSentences.php** which is executed using the include function; this file retrieves 100 sentences which are to be edited by the administrator. The 100 sentences are stored in a PHP array.
3. **index.php** redirects the user to **sentence_editor.php** which displays the very first sentence to be edited; i.e., the sentence whose id is stored in $ids[0].
4. The user makes the necessary edits in an HTML form, once he submits the form the data he has provided is processed in **process_updateSentence.php** which updates the edited sentence's corresponding row in the database.
5. **process_updateSentence.php** then redirects the administrator to **sentence_editor.php** once more, only, this time the next sentence in the array is displayed; i.e., the sentence whose id is stored in $ids[1].

Repeat steps 4 and 5 *ad nauseam*.

Here is all the code relevant to my question for further clarification:

**fetchSentences.php**

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM sentences LIMIT 100";
$results = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $ids[] = $row['id']; // stores the id of the retrieved sentence
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'fetchSentences.php'; ?>
<html>
  <a href="sentence_editor.php?n=0" class="start">Start!</a>        
</html>
```

**sentence_editor.php**

```
<?php
$n = $_GET['n']; // n represents the index of the ids[] array
$id = $ids[$n]; // gets the id of the next sentence to be edited. My problem lies in this line. I am referencing an array $ids[] which was declared in a different file (namely, fetchSentences.php).
// How can I reference $ids[] in this file???
// If I add "include 'fetchSentences.php'" this will end up executing the fetchSentences.php code all over again resulting in an entirely new array of sentence IDs. 
/*
 * code which fetches the sentence from the database
 */
?>

<html>
 <form method="post" action="process_updateSentence.php?id=<?php echo $id?>&n=<?php echo $n?>">
```

**process_updateSentence.php**

```
<?php
header("Location: sentence_editor.php?n=" . ++$n);
?>
```

Comment: start a session and store the sentences in there. It persists page loads so you wouldn't have to requery for the data.

Comment: There's probably a better pattern to follow - can you help us understand **why** you don't want to include the fetch sentences file again?  And I'd challenge you to consider making these *functions*, not individual files, so that you can more easily access information as needed.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Hi Jonathan. Using a session_start seems to have done the trick. Thanks!